# Join SQL confusion?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I was just wondering, can you have 2 ON statments in a join?

I have something like:

```
SELECT table1.col1, table2.col2 
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.col1 = table2.col1 
ON table1.col2 >= table2.col2;
```

Comment: What r u trying to with 2 ONs, which is not possible by one ON

Comment: I put what I was trying to do, but I just used an `AND` and solved the issue

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this can easily be tried out.

Comment: Fair enough. I would delete it if I could, but unfortunately, that is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine conditions with `and` and `or` like

```
select * 
from tableA
join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.id
           and tableA.col2 = tableB.col3
```